# How to read wordpress password protected feed using SimplePie

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed, simplepie

I am trying to read wordpress feed which is password protected using simplepie .
No where i see this issue has been answered

I am testing url feed in simplepie demo page 
[image]

Once we click on read button , as feed is password protected it will redirect to login page and shows this error[image]

I have username and password , but not sure where i can add username and password so that the feed contents are accessible to me

Answer (score 0):

One common convention for this is to embed them in the URL. i.e. turn this:

```
https://intranet.your-domain.com/feed/rss2
```

into this:

```
https://myusername:mypassword@intranet.your-domain.com/feed/rss2
```

Normally this would be a security issue, but if the site is https, as yours appears to be, then I think it should be okay, as your traffic is being encrypted already.

Comment: adding username and password to URL isn't working , it is redirecting to login page